# Azure PowerBI authentication without redirecting to another page

Tags: azure, authentication, adal, powerbi

Is it possible to get an access token for `PowerBI` without redirecting to another page? I'm developing a web app that already contains a login mechanism and I don't to require two logins. Is [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) suitable for my case?

Comment: Can you have your user log in the first using OAuth? Or is that out of your control?

Comment: My existing authentication is auth but it doesn't use AAD

Answer (score 1):

If your existing authentication is using an AAD application, and the user's credential are the same for your app and their power bi account, then if your application has rights to both your app and Power BI, you should get an access token that you can use for both AAD and Power BI.

In most case the above isn't the case - the user will have a different account for Power BI. So you have two options.  The first (and recommended way) is to show the login for Power BI once, save the refresh token you get back and then use the refresh token to get new access tokens.  This isn't perfectly matching your ask - there is a periodic need to do the redirect workflow (first time, and if refresh token expires) but it does ensure you don't have to store and manage the user's credentials.

The second ( and not recommended way) is to use the ADAL username + password workflow.  There's a [great blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) you can review and decide if you want to use this workflow.

Comment: My existing authentication is not using an AAD application.. ADAL can be used in an php/javascript project developed with intellij IDEA? Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm not an ADAL expert - if someone else could jump in it would be appreciated -- the blog i linked to mentions that  the ADAL library for username and password is only provided for C#.  I believe the ADAL library just wraps a REST API ... might be laborious but you should be able to make it work.

Comment: We do have javascript ADAL versions, but you won't be able to use username/passwords with them. The username/password flow can only be used by native clients.
If you already have your own login system, the correct way to handle this is by driving an oauth2 flow for getting an access token and refresh token - this is no different from what you would do when you want to connect your facebook account to your twitter account, you will have to authenticate with facebook at least once while you do so. Example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-useridentity

Comment: If i do this, will i have the right permissions to view the PowerBi report? I use Intellij IDEA (not Visual Studio, nor ASP.NET). When i go to azure active directory and try to add my web app, Power BI Service doesn't appear to "add permissions to other applications".